# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, android

I trying to save resource id of  an image in sharedpreferences on button click and then trying to set that resid to the image. But i am getting "String cannot cast to Integer" error. My question can be silly but I want to solve it. I will be much thankful for that .My code is here.

```
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int res=R.drawable.kiss;
            image.setImageResource(res);
            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),res);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

default value if key not exist
`int defaultimageres=R.mipmap.ic_launcher;`

Error I am getting in line below.

```
int storedImageres=sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),defaultimageres);
```

and here I am setting the resId to image

```
image.setImageResource(storedImageres);
```

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pra1.savingdatasample/com.example.pra1.savingdatasample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
                  at com.example.pra1.savingdatasample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here is my onCreate method: I know its complete mess :P

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    int defaultimageres=R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    String defaultvaluetext1=getResources().getString(R.string.text1);
    String storedtext1=sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.keytextview1),defaultvaluetext1);
    int storedImageres=sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),defaultimageres);
    image.setImageResource(storedImageres);
    tv1.setText(storedtext1);

    String defaultvaluetext2=getResources().getString(R.string.text2);
    String storedtext2=sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.keytextview2),defaultvaluetext2);
    tv2.setText(storedtext2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String text1=ed1.getText().toString();
            if(text1.equals(null)||text1.equals("")){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"empty text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                tv1.setText(text1);
                editor.putString(getString(R.string.keytextview1), text1);
                editor.apply();
                ed1.setText("");
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed1.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String text2= ed2.getText().toString();
            if(text2.equals(null)||text2.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"empty text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                tv2.setText(text2);
                editor.putString(getString(R.string.keytextview2), text2);
                editor.apply();
                ed2.setText("");
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed2.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int res=R.drawable.rtl;
            image.setImageResource(res);
            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),res);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int res=R.drawable.kiss;
            image.setImageResource(res);
            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),res);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why you are using getString ? getInt(getString( here

Comment: Upldate your logcat error too

Comment: getString(R.string.keyimage1)   here i am getting my key stored in string.xml file  " <string name="keyimage1">com.SavingDataSample.image</string>"

Comment: The stored value in shared prefs is a String value, But according to the code, you are storing int. So I am guessing you stored a string previously. So try to uninstall and install the app again to check the problem solved

Comment: With your logs, problem looks something else, can you upload whole onCreate method please

Comment: what is the value of keyimage1 in your strings.xml file?

Comment: com.SavingDataSample.image

Comment: I thing sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.keyimage1),defaultimageres); is not returning string value. So try sharedPreferences.getInt("com.SavingDataSample.image",defaultimageres); once and if this works then debug the value which you get by sharedprefrences. It will be much good if you make this value constant instead of retrieving from strings.xml file.

Comment: @anand singh I tried as you told me but still getting that same error. I think may be R.drawable.imagename   my be not int. I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends thanks for your comments but i solve it my self. I convert int to String and try it with editor.putString method

code in onclick method:

```
 b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int res=R.drawable.kiss;
            String resnew=String.valueOf(res);
            image.setImageResource(res);
            editor.putString(IMAGE_KEY,resnew);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

this is my key

```
 private static final String IMAGE_KEY="com.SavingDataSample.image";
```

these are changes

```
    int defaultimageres=R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    String deafultimageValue=String.valueOf(defaultimageres);

    String storedImageres=sharedPreferences.getString(IMAGE_KEY,deafultimageValue);
    image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(storedImageres));
```